# How to add sender to a macro that sends emails in VBA excel

Tags: vba, excel, email

I've found a piece of code on the internet that sends out emails with attachments depending on an excel spreadsheet's data. The code works perfectly but what i would like to know is how can i change the mailbox from which the emails are coming from? Currently they go from the user who presses send's mailbox. But what i would like is for them to come from a specific mailbox that the user has access to, see code below:

```
Sub Send_Files()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range
Dim FileCell As Range
Dim rng As Range

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set sh = Sheets("Sending Tool")

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

For Each cell In sh.Columns("D").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

    'Enter the File Path in E1, you can add more files and extend the range if needed
    Set rng = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("E1:K1")

    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
       Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        With OutMail
            .to = cell.Value
            .Subject = "Email Header"
            ' This is the body of the email, change the next line to change the email's contents. use "<br>" to create a line break in the email
            .HTMLBody = "Good Morning " & cell.Offset(0, -3).Value & "," & "<br>" & "<br>" & "Body" 
            For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                If Trim(FileCell) <> "" Then
                    If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
                        .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
                    End If
                End If
            Next FileCell

            .Send  'Or use .Display
        End With

        Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If
Next cell

Set OutApp = Nothing
With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

MsgBox ("Emails Sent Successfully")

End Sub
```

For the sake of my example let's call the mailbox userhelp@example.co.uk, I would like for this to be the outgoing mailbox so that should a recipient wish to reply it would come back there rather than the user's personal email.

Comment: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/account.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.ReplyRecipientNames = "userhelp@example.co.uk"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Nathan, i ended up using:

    `.SentOnBehalfOfName = "Userhelp@example.co.uk"
                .To = cell.Value
                .Subject = "Eail Header"`

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.